# How to host website in S3 and CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to host my Angular website using CloudFront, S3, and Amazon EC2
instances. I am creating a bucket for e.g. bucket_name and creating 3 folders in it naming:-
1. example 
2. login 
3. logout

And my URL is:-
1. abc.com/example/ 
2. abc.com/example/login 
3. abc.com/example/logout

But when I host my website I am able to access abc.com/example/ but the issue I am facing is that when I tried to access login and logout URL I am getting an error "404 not found". Because it is trying to locate index.html in the example folder of the S3 bucket like in this way example/login/index.html and EC2 instance is for API calls.

Answer (score 1):

To host your site on S3 bucket and aws CloudFront you must include your parent file index.html in S3 bucket and after this you need to configure static website hosting under properties of S3 bucket. Set these fields as `use this bucket to host website` then enter index document `index.html` ***this file must be in S3 bucket***, and save this.

Next step you can edit public access of this bucket, if you want this site accessible outside world then `turn off` block public access under **Permissions tab** of S3 bucket.

Later, to host this using CloudFront you need to create **CloudFront distribution**, and set `Origin Domain name = Your S3 bucket name` and **Default Root Object** to your parent index.html file (which is stored in s3 bucket) and save this CloudFront distribution, now check the **Domain name URL** on browser, it should work fine.

After completing this you can setup your EC2 instance for back-end API calls as per your needs.

Comment: okie... have you tried adding invalidator to your cloudfront distribution, if not then add invalidator as /* and save it and then try. It should work now I guess :)

Comment: No... So for workaround, we are creating two buckets and two cloud fronts for now.   :p

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep pages like login.html and logout.html. That should work.